# Text classification - Multiple texts for a single instance (Deep Learning)

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, text-classification

My task is to create a classification model (e.g. DDN, RNN) which as an input should accept list of texts and should produce a binary output (good, bad). Of-course the texts will be preprocess accordingly.

As en example let's consider classifying customers (good/bad) based on their emails. There are different number of emails for every customer and some of them have thousands of emails. It will be nice if the latest emails have greater importance and have bigger impact on a prediction.

What is a typical approach to this kind of problem?

I see only two possibilities right now:

1. Combine all emails into one long text. Now we have simple text classification task. But all emails are accounted equally.
2. Treat each email as separate instance in the training set, with the same label (good/bad) as the owner of the email. In the end calculate weighted average predictions for emails (newer emails will have higher weight) and take it as prediction for a customer.

Comment: Will you have label for each eMail or the whole list ?